# embedded JavaScript on the client side security

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security

1) One way to put javascript on the client side is EJS e.g.

```
    <h1> <%= title  %> </h1>
```

where title is a variable.

2) Another way is to use back ticks and insert html or append etc using a library like jQuery

```
    $('h1').html(`{obj.title}`);
```

3) A third way is to use react js esx, so import all the files on the client side if you are going down that route and add an variable as follows:

```
     <div id="holder1"></diV>

     var title = React.createClass({
                      render: function(){
                         return(
                             <h1 className="title1">{this.props.title1}<h1>
                        )
                      } 
                 });
     ReactDOM.render(<title
             title1: "Hello World"  />,
             document.getElementById("holder1")
     );
```

My question is how does react.js handle security so that the javascript cannot be manipulated such as a password on the client side (Not server side) and for 1-2 how can you enforce data hiding and prevent someone from changing the values.  Can this only be done using server side react.js using node.

Let me clarify:  How does React.js and other javascript libraries make the front end more secure... not just passwords... that can be handled with bcrypt hashes and https.

Comment: 1 method of attack is html injection another is form submission.  How can I make the javascript or esx more secure?  or is the biggest risk to the end-user?

Comment: You can do it but i have never heard about anyone doing it, for each input in the password field you could replace it with a random letter, and then encrypt the the letter or the current letters, so someone wouldn't easily see the real input. Then when the user clicks submit, the entire string is decrypted and hashed (assuming HTTPS), then sent to the server

Comment: Can you inject javascript into a page to manipulate form submission or is this unheard of?  I just never really have thought about JS security

Comment: Yes you can just give a script to user and then they run it, alternatively, all browser extensions can also execute a script on the users behalf, so they can also do bad stuff, so by changing the values of the input you can obfuscate it, but then again, its the users job to be careful, you can only rely on the server-side code

Comment: @Pavlo so if im using reactjs, I can dynamically change the password field to a hash on keyup to prevent man in the middle attacks.  Lol this is going back to my university days but I never got an idea of the tools that someone needs to use to enhance security

Comment: If you hash on keyup you are screwed, how will you revert it back to the actual letter. Doing hash on one letter is easy to brute force. But hashing a word is much harder brute force, so you just need a temporary encryption on keyup.

Comment: 1 way encryption.....

Comment: How does that prevent man in the middle? Use HTTPS

Comment: what im thinking about is you add a hash to each letter on key up, saved and copied  on the server end and then bcrypt the entire password.  so not impossible if overkill.  The best way is like pavlo said replace it with a random letter at end of input and match it to the server end code so if the password is read the hash will be secure and then https will encrypt it over the network.

Comment: Take a 6 year old mentality they make up an imaginary language and communciate via letters.  If you know what each word and number translates into then you can save complex passwords to paper or even a file.  A real world scenario would be to use 1) a proxy and vpn 2) not a cheap web host in your local country where they ask what your password is (not that they cant get it) 3) think and learn of an abstract language 4) write complex algorithms using bcrypt 5) use https  6) do everything on the server of your web or cloud host.. a more secure one...

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking, but as a very general rule, anything in the client can't be trusted.

Input posted to the server from the client can't be trusted, and should not be later displayed without proper precautions.

Web security is a huge topic. So I suggest you break your question down into smaller chunks and really identify what you are trying to ask.

Regarding React - it's not doing anything special around passwords. Its the responsibility of the backend service layer to protect from malicious input - there is a very real chance that a React component would send back crappy/malicious data. (not Reacts fault, nor is it the intent of React)

The only thing React has in this regard is `{}` vs `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`, but again, thats not going to protect passwords or the like.

Comment: How does Reactjs in general make the front end more secure?

Comment: It doesn't, if anything it makes it less secure because developers import libraries left right and center and they have idea what the code might be doing

Comment: As per my answer, React doesn't do anything special around its security (with the exception of escaping when not using dangerouslySetInnerHtml) - its a view layer, nothing more.